# Is there a 'push to talk' button on gamepad for GTA Online?

Tags: pc, controllers, grand-theft-auto-online, voice-chat

Is there a push-to-talk button for voicechat on gamepad in the PC port of GTA Online?

If not, is there a way to map the Xbox contoller scheme for this? (I am using PS3 controller and SCP Server.)

For now I use voice-activated + mute, but I prefer using push-to-talk so that my fellow gamers don't have to listen to me yell at my kids and wife.

Comment: I was literally asking this of people last night.. and then realized they could not hear me anyways :D .. But seriously no.. I have not found a push to talk button on the controller.

Comment: You can set your buttons in the game options. You can also set buttons of your controller. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that there is no way to do this in-game for the gamepad.

For `en-us` keyboard the `N` key will activate push-to-talk by default.

However, various utils (depending on your gamepad) can be used to map one of the gamepad buttons to the push-to-talk button (`N` key).

Since this game makes good use of all gamepad buttons, remapping one of the gamepad buttons for push-to-talk is unreasonable to do, and therefore the best option when doing voice chat with GTAV:PC is to use voice-activated+mute.

*DISCLAIMER*

Yes, I know that this is the norm for console gamers, but us oldskool PC gamers are used to push-to-talk. It is especially handy for those of us with large/busy households, or who are gaming in public / cafes / etc which is the great thing about PC games: you can play them on a laptop!

Comment: Can you add more information about these utilities?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can setup in settings > key binds a setting for a gamepad button